# How to Get the logged in User ID in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In my application I used the scaffolding method for creating authentication fast. But I just got one problem while playing with it. Actually I can get `Auth::user()->name` current logged in user username and other details but I can't get the user ID , I tried to get the ID with  `Auth::user()->id` and  `Auth::id()` but all in vain. Is there any method to get the current logged in user ID ?

**What I tried :**

I created a variable in AuthServiceProvider and then tried to get the ID in view like this

**ServiceProvider**

```
$id = Auth::id();
view()->share('id', $id);
```

**View**

> ```
> >  <li><a href="{{ url('/users/{!! $id !!}') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn
> > fa-sign-out"></i>Profile</a></li>
> ```

**Next Try in View:**

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/users/{!!Auth::user()->id!!}') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Profile</a></li>
```

I want to get the logged in user ID so that I can show every user his/her profile.

Comment: I'm using `Auth::user()->id` and It's working. Try to put a `dd(Auth::user()->id)`.

Comment: <li><a href="{{ url('/users/'.Auth::user()->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Profile</a></li> This worked for me.Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a `{!! !!}` echo inside a `{{ }}`, but you can't nest those. It's like having `<?php echo <?php echo ... ?> ?>`. The nested printing is also inside quotes. Assuming that your `id`variable is correctly set, here's how the call should look:

```
<a href="{{ url('/users/' . $id) }}">
```

Much easier too read, right? :)

Comment: ID is not coming in URL !

Comment: <li><a href="{{ url('/users/'.Auth::user()->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Profile</a></li> This worked for me.Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

in View try this:
 `{{ Auth::user()->name }}`

in Controller try this:
 `\Auth::user()->id;`